# Why do I get "Internal Server Error" with PHPStorm and XAMPP on Localhost as soon as I add more code?

Tags: xampp, phpstorm

I am working with PHPStorm and XAMPP on Win7. Both works fine, but at some point I start getting "500 Internal Server Error PhpStorm 9.0.2" as soon as I add more code e.g. a new `<div></div>`. When I delete it again, it works again. The same code works on webhosting but not on localhost.

What could be the issue?

That just makes no sense, why would adding a new `div` cause an server error?
There are no logs about this issue in the `error.log` or `php_error_log`.
Found out that there is a IDE-error log, it says:

> 2015-11-08 17:49:28,975 [6667034]  ERROR - ains.io.fastCgi.FastCgiService - readerIndex(5) + length(1) exceeds writerIndex(5): CompositeByteBuf(ridx: 5, widx: 5, cap: 8189, components=2) 
>   java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: readerIndex(5) + length(1) exceeds writerIndex(5): CompositeByteBuf(ridx: 5, widx: 5, cap: 8189, components=2)
>       at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.checkReadableBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:1138)
>       at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.readByte(AbstractByteBuf.java:542)
>       at org.jetbrains.io.fastCgi.FastCgiService.a(FastCgiService.java:197)
>       at org.jetbrains.io.fastCgi.FastCgiService.responseReceived(FastCgiService.java:170)
>       at org.jetbrains.io.fastCgi.FastCgiDecoder.contentReceived(FastCgiDecoder.java:128)
>       at org.jetbrains.io.fastCgi.FastCgiDecoder.contentReceived(FastCgiDecoder.java:15)
>       at org.jetbrains.io.Decoder.readContent(Decoder.java:68)
>       at org.jetbrains.io.fastCgi.FastCgiDecoder.messageReceived(FastCgiDecoder.java:75)
>       at org.jetbrains.io.Decoder.channelRead(Decoder.java:38)
>       at io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerInvokerUtil.invokeChannelReadNow(ChannelHandlerInvokerUtil.java:84)
>       at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerInvoker.invokeChannelRead(DefaultChannelHandlerInvoker.java:153)
>       at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:187)
>       at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:947)
>       at io.netty.channel.oio.AbstractOioByteChannel.doRead(AbstractOioByteChannel.java:147)
>       at io.netty.channel.oio.AbstractOioChannel$1.run(AbstractOioChannel.java:44)
>       at io.netty.channel.ThreadPerChannelEventLoop.run(ThreadPerChannelEventLoop.java:52)
>       at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:834)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>       at org.jetbrains.ide.PooledThreadExecutor$1$1.run(PooledThreadExecutor.java:56)
>   2015-11-08 17:49:28,975 [6667034]  ERROR - ains.io.fastCgi.FastCgiService - PhpStorm 9.0.2  Build #PS-141.2462 
>   2015-11-08 17:49:28,975 [6667034]  ERROR - ains.io.fastCgi.FastCgiService - JDK: 1.8.0_51 
>   2015-11-08 17:49:28,976 [6667035]  ERROR - ains.io.fastCgi.FastCgiService - VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM 
>   2015-11-08 17:49:28,976 [6667035]  ERROR - ains.io.fastCgi.FastCgiService - Vendor: Oracle Corporation 
>   2015-11-08 17:49:28,976 [6667035]  ERROR - ains.io.fastCgi.FastCgiService - OS: Windows 7 
>   2015-11-08 17:49:28,976 [6667035]  ERROR - ains.io.fastCgi.FastCgiService - Last Action: ShowLog

Comment: You are using PhpStorm's own simple built-in web server. For some reason it shows those errors. If you have XAMPP .. then use XAMPP.

Comment: Yes, that solves the problem. Is there a way to tell PHPStorm to use XAMPP instead of its built in server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using PhpStorm's own simple built-in web server. For some reason it shows those errors. If you have XAMPP .. then just XAMPP.

For that you need to create an Deployment entry where you will specify your base URL which PhpStorm will use to open files in browser. For that:

1. `Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Deployment`
2. Create and configure new deployment entry ("In Place" should be fine)
3. Do not forget to mark it as Default for this project

Now IDE will use URL specified there instead of built-in web server.

---

As for actual error:

1. Please try latest & recently released PhpStorm v10
2. Try changing your PHP version (in case if you have upgraded it recently)
3. Submit bug report ticket to JetBrains' [Issue Tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WI)  if you wish keep using built-in web server for devs to look into.